# Match the given Coordinates from the template in the scaled and rotated image using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, orb, opencv-solvepnp

[This is the image taken from the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKeUV.jpg)
I am trying to get the camera position and yaw, pitch, roll angle of the camera. But I am stuck in pointing the deformed object in the picture.

My approach is -

1) Find the matching coordinates using ORB algorithm but I'm stuck as I can't find anything to get the coordinates.
   2) Then have to find the Object and Image matrices using the coordinates.
   3) Apply solvePnP

I need help in finding the exact matching coordinates of the template. In my case it's a QR code.

I need to match the position, orientation of the QR code in the picture and find the camera position and angles.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Any code or images would help us (and in turn you) to pin point the problem and the solution

Comment: @RickM. This is the link to the image taken from the camera. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKeUV.jpg .. I am trying to find the position and angle of the camera to take that picture. I have the actual picture of QR code with me

Comment: The corner coordinates should be provided by the QR reader. This article could help you find the transformation coefficients: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674433/Perspective-Projection-of-a-Rectangle-Homography